# tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.PermissionDeniedError: Error executing an HTTP request: HTTP response code 403 with body running OpenAI repo

Tags: tensorflow.js, openai-api

I wanted to run OpenAI's repository https://github.com/openai/lm-human-preferences,
but after setting `gcloud auth application-default login`, I kept getting the following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/alison/lm-human-preferences/lm_human_preferences/train_policy.py", line 425, in train
    encoder = m.encoding.get_encoder()
  File "/home/alison/lm-human-preferences/lm_human_preferences/language/encodings.py", line 161, in get_encoder
    encoder_dict = json.loads(read_file(self.encoder_path).decode())
  File "/home/alison/lm-human-preferences/lm_human_preferences/language/encodings.py", line 119, in read_file
    return fh.read()
  File "/home/alison/.local/share/virtualenvs/lm-human-preferences-IIESL3cR/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/lib/io/file_io.py", line 128, in read
    length = self.size() - self.tell()
  File "/home/alison/.local/share/virtualenvs/lm-human-preferences-IIESL3cR/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/lib/io/file_io.py", line 104, in size
    return stat(self.__name).length
  File "/home/alison/.local/share/virtualenvs/lm-human-preferences-IIESL3cR/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/lib/io/file_io.py", line 735, in stat
    return stat_v2(filename)
  File "/home/alison/.local/share/virtualenvs/lm-human-preferences-IIESL3cR/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/lib/io/file_io.py", line 754, in stat_v2
    return file_statistics
  File "/home/alison/.local/share/virtualenvs/lm-human-preferences-IIESL3cR/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/errors_impl.py", line 528, in __exit__
    c_api.TF_GetCode(self.status.status))
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.PermissionDeniedError: Error executing an HTTP request: HTTP response code 403 with body '{
  "error": {
    "code": 403,
    "message": "alison.cs09@nycu.edu.tw does not have storage.objects.get access to the Google Cloud Storage object. Permission 'storage.objects.get' denied on resource (or it may not exist).",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "alison.cs09@nycu.edu.tw does not have storage.objects.get access to the Google Cloud Storage object. Permission 'storage.objects.get' denied on resource (or it may not exist).",
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "forbi'
     when reading metadata of gs://gpt-2/encodings/main/encoder.json
```

This happens with every `.json` file it ran.

I looked up the internet and there were little information about this specific error, and the discussions in the repo mentioned to download the `.json` files and run with them locally, but I couldn't find where they put the `.json` files.